# wordpress - check if slug exists with AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url, slug

I would like to check from the user interface if a slug url already exists.

I naturally turned to an AJAX solution like this.

```
`jQuery("#slugBrut").keyup(function() {
        var slugBrutText = jQuery("#slugBrut").val() ; 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "theme/is_valid_slug.php", 
            data:{
                slug : slugBrutText
            },
            success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }});
    });`
```

And on the called script side `is_valid_slug.php`, it looks like this

```
`<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
$slug = $_POST['slug'] ;
$post_if = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name like '$slug'");
echo $post_if ; // returns 0 or 1`
```

Everything works fine. However, I am not a wordpress pro and I would like to know if this way of doing things is dangerous and if another approach would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are coding in custom plugin or theme (any files in wp-content) No need to require wp-load.php .
if you want better way for create ajax in WP fallow this [AJAX wordpress document](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

NOTE : you can write callback in functions.php in your theme directory or child theme .

NOTE 2 : Also you can use this wp function Instead SQL query.

```
$exists = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, $post_type );
 return (int) $exists; // 1 or 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot! looks like a better direction. I always fear to interact with the database. I'll go see the AJAX documentation to create a callback